# ERROR New-ADUser :The supplied user buffer is not valid

Tags: windows, powershell, server, scripting

[I made a PowerShell script to create Active Directory users from a CSV file. For one specific user I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIDoW.png)

As you can see, the user has been successfully created though. All other users have been made as well. Does anyone know what this error means?

Script:

```css
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$csv_file = Read-Host -Prompt "Path naar CSV bestand?"
$pwd = Read-Host -Prompt "Password for users?" -AsSecureString
$csv_file = $csv_file.Replace('"','')
$csv_list = Import-Csv $csv_file

$domainname = Get-ADDomain
$domainname = $domainname.DNSRoot
$server = hostname
$usernames = (get-aduser -Filter *).name
$i = 0
foreach ($adUser in $csv_list) {

    

    $department = $adUser.Department
    if ($adUser.GivenName) {
         $givenname = $adUser.GivenName
}
    else {
         $givenname = $adUser.FirstName
}

    if ($adUser.Surname) {
         $surname = $adUser.Surname
}
    else {
         $surname = $adUser.LastName
}
    $username = ("${givenname}.${surname}" -replace (' ','')).ToLower()
    if ($username -in $usernames -eq $true) {
    $number = 1
    }
    $variableusername = $username
    while ($variableusername -in $usernames -eq $true) {
         $number += 1
         $variableusername = [string]($username + $number)
}
    $username = $variableusername
    $usernames += $username

    $sam = $username
    if ($sam.Length -gt 20) {
        $sam = $sam.Substring(0,20)
    }
    $path = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * | Where-Object -Property Name -eq $department).DistinguishedName | Select-Object -First 1
    if ($path -eq $False) {
        $department = Read-Host -Prompt "Could not find an OU for user $username in department ${department}. Please specify the correct OU"
        $path = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * | Where-Object -Property Name -eq $department).DistinguishedName | Select-Object -First 1
}
    $password = $pwd
    $email = "${username}@${domainname}"
    $title = $adUser.Title
    $dpn = "${givenname} ${surname}"
    New-ADUser -name $username -path $path -UserPrincipalName "${username}@${domainname}"  -GivenName $givenname -Surname $surname -Department $department -AccountPassword $password -EmailAddress $email -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False -Title $title -Enabled $True -Server $server -DisplayName $dpn -SamAccountName $sam
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "G_${department}" -Members $sam

    $i++
    Write-Progress -activity "Creating users . . ." -status "Created: $i of $($csv_list.Count)" -percentComplete (($i / $csv_list.Count)  * 100)

}
```

Comment: Is this one user in an OU that is different from everyone else? Maybe there is a security policy there that won't let you set the password or enable the user. I see the user is created but it is not enabled even though you flagged it to enable. Honestly, though it seems like an incompatible password, but I don't know why it would work for others and not this one person.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick response. She is not in a different OU from everyone else. When I tried enabling her in the server manager GUI, I get the same error.

Comment: If you run a `Set-ADAccountPassword` on that same user with the same password, does it work?

Comment: It didn't. However, I just deleted all the users I made with the script, ran the script again and this time it worked without any error.